# multgee for repeated measure multinomial regression

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, biostatistics, generalized-estimating-equations

I am trying to analize my experiment results according to the multgee reference pdf, but I have some warning message.

My dependent variable is a 5 level categorical variable. I have 12 eyes of 6 rat, examined 4 time daily for 3 days. 
My ID is a numerical variable (1 -> 12), different for each rat and each eyes between rats. 
The grouping variable is a 2 level categorical variable (Drug). 
I want to know if there are any significant differences in terms of the 5 levels of the dependent variable between subject and within subject (repeated measure) among drugs.

here a `str()` report of my data:

```
 Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  264 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ Eye                            : chr  "R.E" "L.E" "R.E" "L.E" ...
 $ Drug                           : chr  "Study D" "None" "Study D" "None" 
 $ Timepoint                      : num  0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 ...
 $ Corneal_Defect                 : Factor w/ 5 levels "No staining",..: 1 1 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 1 ...
 $ newid                          : num  1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
>
```

My code, according to reference manual is:

> intrinsic.pars( y = Controlli$Corneal_Defect, data = Controlli, id = newid, repeated = Timepoint,rscale = "ordinal")

and the results (that require more than 30 minutes), with the first warning are:

```
 [1] -1.485344e+00 -6.996468e-01 -1.179613e+01 -1.179301e+01
  [5] -6.428373e+00 -1.365166e+01 -4.638385e-01 -2.289868e-01
  [9] -9.975028e-02 -7.761781e-01 -6.750473e-01 -1.107365e+00
[...] 
[229] -2.537813e-01 -2.537813e-01  2.197225e+00
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred
```

When i try to fit the model `fit <- ordLORgee(formula = Corneal_Defect ~ factor(Timepoint) + factor(Drug),link = "logit", id = newid, repeated = Timepoint, data = Controlli,LORstr = "uniform")`

I have this error:

```
Error in fitLORgee(Y, X_mat, coeffs, ncategories, id, repeated, offset,  : 
  Robust covariance matrix is not positive definite
In addition: Warning message:
In eval(slot(family, "initialize")) :
  response should be ordinal---see ordered()
```

Can someone please help me?? Moreover, if there are other packages of statistical tools to perform the analysis I need please, can you suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the second problem: try 'ordered(Corneal_Defect)' in the model formula.
If the covariance structure is still no positive definite then, try a different (easier) structure.

Regarding the first problem: save the results of intrinsic.pars and have a look at them via the summary() function.